# Дополнительные HTTP заголовки в запросе без использования AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-заголовки

Здравствуйте возникла необходимость передать дополнительную информацию на сервер, используя метод GET но при этом не засоряя строку запроса. Вижу единственный способ это передать дополнительные заголовки куда вставить нужную мне инфу и на сервере прочитать эти заголовки. Но пока вижу что доп заголовки можно прицепить только если использовать Ajax но мне он не нужен. Не подскажите как передать доп заголовки или может есть какой другой способ?

Comment: "передать дополнительную информацию на сервер" - метод GET получает информацию и поэтому так называется. Может вам просто нужен POST, который предназначен для отправки данных?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Я думаю, он имеет в виду какие то значения для фильтрации, например. А тут уже на любителя. Кому то нравится на беке проводить подобные махинации, а кому то на фронте.

Comment: @Митяй не понял вас. Как заголовки в запросе помогают фильтрации лучше, чем тело запроса? И то и другое идёт в тексте http-запроса. Только заголовки предназначены для служебной информации, а автор зачем-то их хочет использовать для таких целей, для которых придумано тело запроса.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev С чего вы решили что я пишу о заголовках? Я вообще его хотелку в принципе описываю)

Answer (score 1):

Я так полагаю вы используете XHR для отправки запросов? тогда как то так:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open   = function () {
    this.origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setRequestHeader('X-TOKEN', 'token');
};
```

---

Если использовать axios - то примерно так:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-TOKEN'] = 'token';
```

Comment: в том то и дело что XHR  мне нельзя использовать в данной ситуации, вообщем решил вопрос как мне кажется элементарно и элегантно. Если до завтра никто не ответит, напишу свой ответ

Comment: @ahel73 напишите сегодня ) просто не говорите, что он конечный. Интересно же видеть элементарное решение как передать заголовок без ajax.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev  я сделал следующее, при клике в браузере на определённой сущности, я создаю форму указываю путь  который мне нравиться, метод делаю пост, а в инпуты закидываю всю необходимую информацию, потом просто отправляю форму тоже программно, после чего происходит перезагрузка страницы с нужным мне урлом а в нужный мне метод попадает вся необходимая информация. Конечно немного подправил роутер, что бы правильно в строке запроса определял контроллер и метод которые должны обработать запрос. Вообщем меня устраивает на сто процентов, для кого то может быть убожеством. дело вкуса)

Comment: @ahel73 я так и хотел предложить вместо заголовков (всё к этому и подводил, просто расследовать сначала почву надо :) ). Способ не убогий а весьма часто используемый.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev в своём вопросе если вы обратите внимание я акцент ставил не про заголовки а про передачу информации. а инфу нельзя передать постом если мы кликаем по например ссылке в итоге засоряется урл. поэтому и был задан этот вопрос передача информации без засорения урла. И инфу передаю в заголовках для нужных целей очень часто, просто есть служебные заголовки ну а можно свои создать это же не запрещено)

Comment: @ahel73 понятно. если б кто-то ещё рассказал как это с заголовками провернуть. можно куки ставить и потом их удалять, будет заголовком тогда, но гемор будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126401/discussion-between-ahel73-and-pavel-grishaev).